# How can I convert the Multiply Add node in Blender 2.79?

Tags: node-editor, mathematics

I need to change node Multiply Add from Blender 4.0.2 to Blender 2.79 with math nodes. How i can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use two nodes one after another in Multiply and Add modes. That's all there is to it - it's exactly the same. Multiply Add mode in the Math node is there only for convenience and it doesn't do anything different than if you do those operations separately.

[image]

Comment: But this node have input Value, i must connect this input in factors of multi and add?

Comment: "Value" in Multiply Add node is the value you want to multiply and add to. So if you connect that value to Multiply node and then take the result and connect it to Add node, you can first multiply it and then add to it. I am not sure how else to explain.

Comment: Maybe that can help? https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHLcF.png multiply add is (a x b) + c

Comment: @UMANETS Also, multiplication is commutative, meaning $a\cdot b = b\cdot a$, so it does not matter if you have _Value · Value_ in the _Multiply_ node, if one _Value_ represents the _Value_ from the _Multiply Add_ node and the other the _Multiplier_, then the result is the same for _Value · Multiplier_ = _Multiplier · Value_. So I'm not sure what your problem is with the setup...? Or do you think every input called _Value_ must have the same number...?

Comment: But we have difference with (a+b)*c or a*c+b

Comment: Yes as the name and the order of sockets implies, the node first multiplies, then adds. So it's always (a*b) + c hence the order or the multiply node and the add node

Comment: @UMANETS But the name is _Multiply Add_ not _Add Multiply_ node, already gives a hint on the order of operations. Also the order of inputs with the _Multiplier_ above the _Adddend_ gives a hint on the order of operations (and this node is not switchable from one order to the other). And the manual setup shown in the answer only allows that order of operations, because the way they are connected can only work in one direction, first the multiplication and then the addition. No doubt about that. And if there still was any doubt for the _Multiply Add_ node, just enter values and check the result.